# If I support a minimum of API 14, what screen densities do I not have to worry about?

Tags: java, android

If I am developing to support a minimum of API 14, do I need to worry about assets for anything lower than hdpi? I am not aware of any device that can use API 14 with a screen density lower than hdpi.

Is it safe to just ignore ldpi and mdpi for my app and only support hdpi and above? This would save alot of time for me and especially my creative team.

Comment: I would not generally say you can ignore densities based on a specific target API level. There might still be cheap tablets running ICS but with a very low-density screen. There are just so many different devices out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Density is independent of API level.

There are `ldpi` and `mdpi` devices being made and sold today, particularly in emerging markets, where there is a strong drive to keep the cost of devices down. The [device dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) show that about 25% of devices currently in use are `ldpi` and `mdpi`. Since the same dashboards show that only 12% of devices run less than API 14, clearly there are API 14+ devices that are `ldpi` and `mdpi`.

From the standpoint of bitmap drawables, Android will automatically downsample for you. If you ship nothing lower than `hdpi`, Android will downsample the `hdpi` images to lower densities so the images are approximately the same size, but hence with fewer pixels. So, get your hands on an `ldpi` and an `mdpi` device and test your app, to see what the bitmaps look like, and only worry about those where the downsampling gives poor results.

Comment: Is there any advantage to doing the downsampling myself and adding ldpi and mdpi folders?

Comment: @stevebot: You gain control, as you are the one defining what the image will be, not a potentially-variable algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for API 14 it does not mean you have to focus only on HDPI, this specifically depends on what is the screen resolution of your target audience. If your target audience has resolution 240x320(ldpi), 320x480 (mdpi) then you have to support mdpi and ldpi.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about the resources for the application, like icons and stuff. You just need to make xxhdpi or a good resolution asset and you can use a program like [Android asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/), or by even using ctrl+N in eclips to scale down for all dpi.

Comment: Thanks, do those tend to scale properly in your experience, or do you have to watch out for blurriness and pixilation?

Comment: They scaled down properly for me always. make sure the asset you provide is a good one, thats's it!

Answer (score 1):

To make a general idea of what's out there in terms of devices, their APIs and screen density, [Blundell](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/about-me/) keeps a list on [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/) blog. This should not mean that if you don't find a device on this table with lower density on the minimum API you're targeting you shouldn't support that density. Here is the copied and pasted list from the blog mentioned above:

```
Model                   | Android Version | Density
Advent Vega             |      2.2        |  mdpi

Amazon Fire TV          |      4.2        |  xhdpi

Asus Transformer Prime  |      4.0        |  hdpi

Freelander PD10         |      4.0        |  hdpi

Google Galaxy Nexus     |      4.0        |  xhdpi
Google Nexus One        |      2.3        |  hdpi
Google Nexus S          |      4.0        |  hdpi
Google Nexus 4          |      4.2        |  xhdpi
Google Nexus 7          |      4.1        |  tvdpi (but will scale down your hdpi assets)
Google Nexus 10         |      4.2        |  xhdpi (Launcher icon xxhdpi)

HTC Desire              |      2.2        |  hdpi
HTC Desire S            |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC Desire X            |      4.0        |  hdpi
HTC Desire HD           |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC Doubleshot          |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC Glacier             |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC Nexus One           |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC Hero                |      2.1        |  mdpi
HTC Legend              |      2.1        |  mdpi
HTC Sensation           |      2.3        |  hdpi
HTC One                 |      4.2        |  xhdpi
HTC One S               |      4.0        |  hdpi
HTC One X               |      4.0        |  xhdpi
HTC One X+              |      4.1        |  xhdpi
HTC One V               |      4.0        |  hdpi
HTC Tattoo              |      1.6        |  ldpi
HTC Wildfire            |      2.1/2.2    |  mdpi

Huawei Blaze            |      2.3        |  mdpi

LG Nexus 4              |      4.2        |  xhdpi
LG Optimus S            |      2.2        |  mdpi
LG Optimus Sol          |      2.3        |  hdpi
LG Optimus One          |      2.2        |  mdpi
LG Optimus V            |      2.2        | mdpi
LG Optimus 3D           |      2.3        |  hdpi

Motorola Atrix          |      2.3        |  hdpi
Motorola Defy           |      2.3        |  hdpi
Motorola Defy Mini      |      2.3        |  mdpi
Motorola Droid          |      2.0-2.2    |  mdpi
Motorola Droid 3        |      2.3        | hdpi
Motorola Flipout        |      2.1        |  ldpi
Motorola Razr           |      2.3        |  hdpi
Motorola Xoom           |      3.1/4.0    |  mdpi
Motorola Xoom2          |      3.2        |  mdpi

Sony X10 Mini           |      2.1        |  ldpi
Sony X10i               |      2.3        |  hdpi
Sony Xperia Arc S       |      2.3        |  hdpi
Sony Xperia P           |      2.3        |  hdpi
Sony Xperia Play        |      2.3        |  hdpi
Sony Xperia Pro         |      4.0        |  hdpi
Sony Xperia S           |      2.3        |  xhdpi
Sony Xperia X8          |      2.1        |  mdpi
Sony Xperia Z           |      4.2        |  xxhdpi

Samsung Epic 4G         |      2.2        |  hdpi
Samsung Galaxy Ace      |      2.2        |  mdpi
Samsung Galaxy S        |      2.3        |  hdpi
Samsung Galaxy S II     |      2.3        |  hdpi
Samsung Galaxy S III    |      4.0        |  xhdpi
Samsung Galaxy S 4      |      4.2        |  xhdpi
Samsung Galaxy S 4 Active |      4.2        |  xhdpi
Samsung Galaxy Tab 7"   |      2.2        |  hdpi
Samsung Galaxy Tab 10"  |      3.0        |  mdpi
Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10"|      4.0        |  mdpi 
Samsung Galaxy Nexus    |      4.0        |  xhdpi
Samsung Galaxy Note     |      2.3        |  xhdpi
Samsung Galaxy Note 2   |      4.1        |  xhdpi
Samsung Nexus 10        |      4.2        |  xhdpi
Samsung Nexus S         |      4.0        |  hdpi

ZTE Blade               |      2.3        |  hdpi
ZTE Libra               |      2.2        |  hdpi
```